# How to fix dependency of Fire Base (FCM) when update android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0.0?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I have working application with Google connection and `FCM` service in android studio 2.3.3
I bought new computer and install android studio 3.0.0 and I transfer my app to it. I can compile it but the `Google button` does not work. What should I do?

Comment: Update your SHA-1 keys for the current app in Firebase console, first of all. As you've migrated your app to new machine, the SHA-1 key for this machine is different than older machine. Generate the key again and replace it in Firebase console.

Comment: It work for me. tanx